# finding an element from one list in another list in python

Tags: python, list, element

Is there a way to have two lists named list1 and list2 and be able to look up the position of one entry in another. i.e.

```
list_one = ["0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

list_two = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
```

my aim is to allow the user to enter a word which the program will then convert in a set of numbers corresponding to the letters entries in list_one

so if the user did input hello the computer would return 85121215 (being the position of the entries)

is there a possible way to do this

Comment: What do you want to do with letters that are duplicated in list1? If there are no duplications or you just want to use the location of the first occurrence, then you could use a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking up the position of an item in a list is not a very efficient operation.  A dict is a better data structure for this kind of task.

```
>>> d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(list_one)}
>>> print(*(d[k] for k in list_two))
8 5 12 12 15
```

If your `list_one` is always just the alphabet, in alphabetical order, it's probably better and simpler to get something working by using the builtin function [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @wim's answer, could be done with a simple comprehension.

```
>>> [list_one.index(x) for x in list_two]
[8, 5, 12, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate thought the list :

```
>>> for i in range(len(list_two)):
...     for j in range(len(list_one)):
...             if list_two[i]==list_one[j]:
...                     list_3.append(j)
>>> list_3
[8, 5, 12, 12, 15]
```

but wim's answer is more elegant !

Answer (score 0):

the `x.index(i)` returns the position of the element `i` of the list `x`

```
print("".join([str(list_one.index(i)) for i in list_two]))
85121215
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.index()` on a list:

```
list_one = ["0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

string = "hello"
positions = [list_one.index(c) for c in string]
print(positions)
# [8, 5, 12, 12, 15]
```